# Strip a string from both sides

Tags: vba

I have this string:

```
"2015-07-22"
```

and I want to extract the `"07"` from the string.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Use Mid() http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_mid.asp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Mid function

```
Mid("2015-07-22", 6, 2)
```